# Blender interface grayed out?

Tags: interface

i have both blender 2.78 and 2.70

the 2.78 version looks fine but for some reason 2.70 is grayed out[image]

Does Anyone know why?

Thank you

Comment: Possibly some graphics driver issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but if you want a normal interface again you can try this:
Open the user preferences and select themes[image]

After that, you can click Reset to Default Theme or choose one of the presets [image]
I hope that I could have helped you and if it is not going to work, please enter the blend file so that I can try a few things out.